# Compiling Okular from source successfully, but experiencing "Could not find plugin okularpart" after opening it

Tags: 22.04, xubuntu, kde, compiling, okular

This is the output after I have compiled and opened Okular.

```
kf.xmlgui: cannot find .rc file "shell.rc" for component "okular"
kf.coreaddons: "Could not find plugin okularpart"
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.